# Using jQuery in javascript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object, this

```js
function count(x,y) {
  this.x;
  this.y;
  this.plus = function() {
    return this.x + this.y;
  }
  this.checkResult = function() {
    $("#test").click(function() {
      this.plus(); //help here
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<p id='test'></p>
```

"this" return the element that's clicked, so how to run method inside jQuery?

Comment: I think you need to learn javascript, then ask questions with what you are struggling. You can start with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : you can store function `this` to some variable and use it.

```js
function count(x,y) {
  this.x;
  this.y;
  this.plus = function() {
    return this.x + this.y;
  }
  this.checkResult = function() {
    var $this = this;
    $("#test").click(function() {
      alert($this.plus()); //help here
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<p id='test'>Click me</p>
```